# Event when boolean is true

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, boolean

I'm programming in c#(WPF). I have some `Boolean` variables in my class like `isConnected` or `isBusy`. I want to define a `event` and `event handler` for them to when my boolean variables are changed, I run a method.

I searched and find some things but I can't understand them.

could you help me to write it?

---

**Update 1:**

finally I write it, but I get StackOverFlowExeception which may be caused by recursion.
what is wrong?

```
    public event EventHandler IsConnectedChanged;

    public bool IsConnected
    {
        get { return IsConnected; }
        set
        {
            IsConnected = value;
            CheckAndCallHandlers();
        }
    }



    private void CheckAndCallHandlers()
    {
        EventHandler handler = IsConnectedChanged;
        if (IsConnected)
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
```

Comment: It helps those who might answer your question if you say what things you found, and what you didn't understand.

Comment: .NET already has an interface you can use for this. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.110).aspx for how to use `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the variable in Properties, and then in the setter for the properties you can call a method that checks to see if both are `true`. When that condition is met, you can then do the extra work:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private bool _isConnected;
    private bool _isBusy;

    public event EventHandler SomeCustomEvent;

    public bool IsConnected
    {
        get { return _isConnected; }
        set
        {
            _isConnected = value;
            CheckAndCallHandlers();
        }
    }

    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get { return _isBusy; }
        set
        {
            _isBusy = value;
            CheckAndCallHandlers();
        }
    }

    private void CheckAndCallHandlers()
    {
        var handler = SomeCustomEvent;
        if(IsConnected && IsBusy && handler != null)
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but I need to define event like MouseClick one.

Comment: @Babak.Abad - You could do exactly that using this method. You would define an event on your class, allow people to register handlers, and then call those handlers when the conditions are met.

Comment: @Babak.Abad - Updated with an example.

Answer (score 1):

make it a property

```
bool _isConnected;
bool isConnected
{
  get { return _isConnected; }
  set {
    if (value != _isConnected) //it's changing!
    {
      doSomething();
    }

    _isConnected = value; //Could do this inside the if but I prefer it outside because some types care about assignment even with the same value.
  }  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but I need to define event like MouseClick one.